# Hiding all default menu items in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I had to remove all the default menus in blackberry. I have used the following code

```
protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {  
        // if you want default menu items, uncomment bellow line  
        // super.makeMenu(menu, instance);  
    }
```

But after this, still it was showing the default menu like "Switch Application", for that i have used `super(NO_SYSTEM_MENU_ITEMS)` in the screen class constructor.

Now all menus are removed, but it is still showing "empty menu" as shown in the image below.[image]

Please let me know how could we remove all menu items and make it empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this  in your main screen

```
public boolean onMenu(int instance) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that.

```
public boolean onMenu(int instance) {
    return super.onMenu(2);
}
```

Because for creating menu instance value is 0. So, for any non zero value it doesn't create the menu.

Comment: whats the difference between the previous answer and this one? they are only only the same.

Comment: Its a basic logic that any integer other then 0 is treated as Boolean true

Comment: Nilanchala: integers and booleans do not have implicit conversion in Java.  Nsr's solution is to change the instance passed to the parent class implementation of onMenu. This likely causes the parent class to return false, so @HelpMeHelpYou has a more direct way of accomplishing that.